# Customer's Phone Number Collection w/PayPal

Tags: customer, paypal

I was wondering if anyone has come up with a way to collect the telephone number of customers that are checking out with PayPal.

If my customer checks out on my website using their credit card number through Authorize.net, they provide their shipping information & contact information to the MagentoCE platform...

However when they use PayPal Express, they also provide the shipping information & contact information to PayPal, however PAYPAL does NOT send back the PHONE Number that the customer enters even though it is a required field. I have phoned PayPal on this, and multiple agents report that the system collects the number, but does not send it to the merchants for privacy reasons.

Unfortunately, we require the phone number of our clients to arrange shipping & other matters, as our products are very large...

Any ideas as to how I would force customers to provide this information to us as well?

Answer (score 9):

PayPal allows to tconfigure this on your merchant account

1. Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com. 
   The My Account Overview page appears.
2. Click the Profile subtab. 
   The Profile Summary page appears.
3. In the Selling Preferences column, click the Website Payment Preferences link.
   Scroll down the page to the Contact Telephone Number section.
4. Select one of the following options:
   *On (Optional Field)* – PayPal lets payers share their telephone numbers with you, as an option.

   *On (Required Field)* – PayPal informs payers that their telephone numbers will be shared with you because you require it.

   *Off (Recommended)* – PayPal does not share payers' telephone numbers with you.
5. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click the Save button.

PayPal does not recommends to turn this on as a required since it may decreases conversion so the compromise in this case is to have "On (Optional Field)" configured

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: as of 2017 My profile -> My selling tools -> Website preferences (click update)  in the same section "Contact Telephone Number"